# how to test an aws lambda function using docker

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, serverless

I am trying to test a simple lambda function using docker on windows.
I already have a docker lambcy/lambda image

But this line:

`docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda`
 does not work on windows.

What is the appropiate way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda
```

The command that you running is targeting linux platform, as for windows platform maybe you can try below instead

```
docker run --rm -it -v %cd%:/var/task lambci/lambda
```